# Check for an empty list in a view in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

I am returning a list of companies in my code and have a requirment to set the page title as the first company name. I am able to do that successfully but the problem appears when the list is empty. The code throws an exception.

I am using asp.net 4.0, MVc3 and entity framework 4.1

```
@model List<% InvoiceSearchTool.Models.Invoices %>

@{

    ViewBag.Title = Model.FirstOrDefault().Company;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Why would you call the view if the list is null? Is this a Create view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to check for a null prior to setting the value:

**Check if the list is null:**

```
ViewBag.Title = (Model != null) ? Model.FirstOrDefault().Company : "";
```

**Check if the list is empty:**

```
ViewBag.Title = (Model.Count() > 0) ? Model.FirstOrDefault().Company : "";
```

*(This would probably help greatly to accomplish this within the ViewModel if possible)*

Comment: does not work.... may be because the model is not null here, it contains an empty list :(

Comment: I added another possibility to the answer to check if the list is empty

Comment: I'd second Rionmonster's comment that accomplishing it in the viewmodel would be a better approach.

Comment: :) even i did the same and it worked... thanks man


ViewBag.Title = Model.Count != 0? Model.FirstOrDefault().Company: "";